# Target shooting with 2 different probability of success

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

I am new into the field of "Probabilites and Statistics" and I try to understand how the following problem can be solved:

There is a target shooting competition. Each participant is allowed to shoot at the target ten times (5 times standing and 5 times lying down). The probability of success at each standing pull is p1 ∈ (0.1) and the probability of success at each standing pull is p2 ∈ (0.1). What is the probability that athlete A will miss the target 3 times?

All can I think of is that it can be solved using Bernoulli distribution but I'm not sure and even if I was I'm kind of confused about how to apply it. The participant could miss the target at any of these 2 kind of shooting (standing and lying down) and I don't know how to combine the success rates in order to obtain the correct result. If anyone can guide me through the process of solving this problem I'll be thankful.

Comment: Hello, why don't you try the binomial distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I looked at the link you attached and the examples from it. If you look at the example with the coin toss I've tryed to apply the same thing for my problem but here I have 2 different probabilities p1 and p2 and I don't know if that works. So if I take 10 shots (5 lying and 5 standing) the probability to miss 3 of them will be: f(3,10,p1+p2) ? and then apply the formula for this?

Comment: as in the answer by Tortar below, the simple method would be to take cases for where the misses happened - ex 3 misses standing, or 2 misses standing 1 miss sitting. There are 4 such cases. Then use the binomial distribution to solve each of the cases, dealing with the standing and sitting cases separately.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. So after I calculate the probability for all 4 cases I should sum up the prbabilities and that is the final answer?

Comment: thats exactly right. You can sum the probabilities as the cases are disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you miss $1$ time standing and $2$ times lying down then you have ${5 \choose 1}$ ways to choose the miss standing and ${5 \choose 2}$ ways for the other one.

Then, the probability is $$\left[{5 \choose 1}p_1^4(1-p_1)\right]\left[{5 \choose 2}p_2^3(1-p_2)^2\right]$$

You can easily translate the classical binomial distribution to this case to understand the calculation. If you do the same for the other cases and sum up you are done

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. So after I calculate the probability for all 4 cases I should sum up the prbabilities and that is the final answer?

Comment: yes that's right :)